Symfony not existing routes after cache update
This is the first time I’ve encountered this, after the bin/console cache:clear non-existent routes appeared, physically such methods no longer exist in the controller, and accordingly it doesn’t see new ones either...
Symfony 5.4
/opt/php81/bin/php bin/console debug:router                                                                                                      
 -------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------                                                                           
  Name                Method   Scheme   Host   Path                            
 -------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  ap_policy           ANY      ANY      ANY    /policy 
  ap_policy_agree     ANY      ANY      ANY    /policy-agree  
  ap_policy_rules     ANY      ANY      ANY    /rules 
  ap_cookies          ANY      ANY      ANY    /cookies 
  ap_features         ANY      ANY      ANY    /features  
  ap_pm1000bg         ANY      ANY      ANY    /pm1000bg                                                                                                  
  ap_mb195bg          ANY      ANY      ANY    /mb195bg

Two routers that are not actually in the PrizeController Controller:
/opt/php81/bin/php bin/console debug:router ap_pm1000bg                                                                                          
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+                                                                                                   
| Property     | Value                                         |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+                                                                                                   
| Route Name   | ap_pm1000bg                                   |                                                                                                   
| Path         | /pm1000bg                                     |                                                                                                   
| Path Regex   | {^/pm1000bg$}sDu                              |                                                                                                   
| Host         | ANY                                           |                                                                                                   
| Host Regex   |                                               |                                                                                                   
| Scheme       | ANY                                           |                                                                                                   
| Method       | ANY                                           |                                                                                                   
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                     |                                                                                                   
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route               |                                                                                                   
| Defaults     | _controller: 
                App\Controller\PrizeController::pm1000Bg()     |                                                                                                   
| Options      | compiler_class: 
                Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler        |                                                                                                   
|              | utf8: true                                    |                                                                                                   
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+


/opt/php81/bin/php bin/console debug:router ap_mb195bg                                                                                          
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+                                                                                                   
| Property     | Value                                         |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+                                                                                                   
| Route Name   | ap_mb195bg                                    |                                                                                                   
| Path         | /mb195bg                                      |                                                                                                   
| Path Regex   | {^/mb195bg$}sDu                               |                                                                                                   
| Host         | ANY                                           |                                                                                                   
| Host Regex   |                                               |                                                                                                   
| Scheme       | ANY                                           |                                                                                                   
| Method       | ANY                                           |                                                                                                   
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                     |                                                                                                   
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route               |                                                                                                   
| Defaults     | _controller: 
                App\Controller\PrizeController::mb195bg()      |                                                                                                   
| Options      | compiler_class: 
                Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler        |                                                                                                   
|              | utf8: true                                    |                                                                                                   
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+ 

My controller PrizeController, no methods mb195bg and pm1000Bg
class PrizeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/policy", name="ap_policy")
     */
    public function policyPage(Request $request)
    {}

    /**
     * @Route("/policy-agree", name="ap_policy_agree")
     */
    public function policyAgreePage(Request $request)
    {}

   /**
    * @Route("/rules", name="ap_policy_rules")
    */
    public function rulesPage(Request $request)
    {}

    /**
     * @Route("/cookies", name="ap_cookies")
     */
    public function cookiesPage(Request $request)
    {}

    /**
    * @Route("/features", name="ap_features")
    */
    public function prizeInfo(Request $request)
    {}
}


comand bin/console cache:clear does not output no errors:
// Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false
[OK] Cache for the "prod" environment (debug=false) was successfully cleared.
All files in the cache folder are created. The problem is only in production.
